# Is there a date/time equivalent for Linux Network namespaces?

Tags: linux, date-time, container

For the network stack one can create separate network namespaces with iproute2 (see https://baturin.org/docs/iproute2/#Network%20namespace%20management). Is there a date/time equivalent? This should be possible, because Linux container instances need a per container system time, after all.

Note: I know about libfaketime, but I'm looking for a tool that makes the Kernel feature accessible from user space.

Edit: According to [The Wikipedia Entry about Linux Namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces) time is currently not namespaced, so the question is moot.

Comment: Some further searching indicates that time is currently not in a separate namespace. See https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/two-objects-not-namespaced-linux-kernel/

Comment: Edit your question.  All relevant information should be contained in the question not in a comment

Comment: If it's mostly for doing functional tests or alike, or perhaps altering a binary as long as it's not statically linked, suid etc., you can try the LD_PRELOAD-based wrapper faketime. See informations there: https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime. It can change the time base as well as the speed of time.

Comment: I knew about faketime, but LD_PRELOAD can be overwritten.The use case was for backdating certificates, so that they remain usable when the target system loses its CMOS battery and those the hardware clock.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is currently no time namespace. See

- https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/two-objects-not-namespaced-linux-kernel/
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html